# Timezones conversion: Using DateTimeZone in PHP, the output is an hour early

Tags: php, datetime

I have a small function:

```
public static function date($input = 'now', $format = 'Y-m-d H:i', $tzFrom, $tzTo) {

        $date = date_create($input, new DateTimeZone($tzFrom))->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone($tzTo));

        if ($format == 'TS') {
            return strtotime($date->format('Y-m-d H:i'));
        }

        return $date->format($format);
}
```

This is it's output:

```
echo '<br>' . DT::date('now', 'TS', 'America/Los_Angeles', 'UTC'); // 1452281400
This is:
1452281400 -> Fri, 08 Jan 2016 19:30:00
```

But it's wrong because current UTC time:     Fri, 08 Jan 2016 20:30:00, not 19:30:00.

Where is the extra 1 hour?  How do I fix my function? 
Thanks!

Comment: this is working for me, what is your system time on the device the program is on?

Comment: My system time: 12:58 PM

Comment: strtotime returns wrong timestamp (-1 hour).

Comment: Ok. Found: return $date->getTimestamp();

Comment: can you figure out if daylight savings time is the issue? being off by one hour sort of points to that.  Try `date("I", time());`

Comment: I believe that should return a 0, as DST ended in november

Comment: I can't seem to get the error. Even trying where daylight saving is active as you can see on my server in Sydney (http://trev.id.au/td). Is there anything else happening in the class? I tried it on php fidle as well and can't get it to fault. Changing default timezone doesn't seem to fault either.

Answer (score 0):

```
function convert_time($timestring,$format="Y-m-d H:i:s",$from,$to){
    $default = date_default_timezone_get(); // get default to reset
    date_default_timezone_set($from); // set the `from` timezone
    $the_date = strtotime($timestring); // given string to time
    date_default_timezone_set($to);  // given string to required zone
    $req_date = date($format,$the_date); // required date in required format
    date_default_timezone_set($default); // reset to default
    return $req_date;
}
```

Hope this helps